# Subclass a custom UIViewController (with xib) to add additional behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, xib

Here's the deal: I'm using the [DEFacebookComposeViewController](https://github.com/joshavant/DEFacebookComposeViewController-Enhanced) which is a custom subclass of a `UIViewController`. This subclass is using an xib to setup the user interface.

Now I want to add some additional GUI elements to `DEFacebookComposeViewController` so I figured I would create a subclass named something like `MySubclassDEFacebookComposeViewController : DEFacebookComposeViewController` and create a xib.

However the xib `MySubclassDEFacebookComposeViewController.xib` is not showing any of the GUI elements from `DEFacebookComposeViewController.xib` which I thought it would do since it's a subclass of that class.

So basically I'm just wondering what is the correct approach in adding new elements to a subclassed `UIViewController` and `xib`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the `DEFacebookComposeViewController.xib` and rename it to `MySubclassDEFacebookComposeViewController.xib` and edit it to your likings.

A UIViewController will look by default for a nib/xib with the same name (even without the controller part at the end) when created

From the docu of UIViewController:

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller’s view, it is
>   recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when
>   initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a
>   nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other
>   means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name
>   (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view
>   is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with
>   one of the following names:
>
> If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as
>   in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>   class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib. It looks
>   for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller
>   class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks
>   for a MyViewController.nib file.

So you need to specify the nib you want to use or name it after the view controller. Since you  want to add/modify the old nib you need a copy of it.

This is assuming that `DEFacebookComposeViewController.xib` does not have any `IBOutlets` by default. If it has you can modify the existing nib in `viewDidLoad`. Adding more subViews can always be accomplished aften the view is loaded regardless if there are `IBOutlets`.

Comment: Alright, what do you mean with "...assuming that DEFacebookComposeViewController.xib does not have any IBOutlets by default." Isn't that the purpose of a xib to have `IBOutlets` that you connect your .h/.m file with Interface Builder? The original `DEFacebookComposeViewController.m` is full of `IBOutlets`.

Comment: It may not be necessary to wire everything up with IBOutlets - though it is not common. If it is "full" of outlets use the outlets to reconfigure the existing views to your liking via code and add new subviews via code.